# defining web root in php for all files access

Tags: php, file, directory

i've been trying to get a work around for this:
in a file structure like this:

```
root:
-----index.php (file inside root)
-----template (folder inside root)
-----user (folder inside root)
-----products  (folder inside root)
-----config  (folder inside root)
```

i've been trying to use `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` inside a file in the config folder to define webroot constant but it is not working well, if i try to access the files from other folders, it's calling webroot from the current folder instead of going back to the root.
pls can any1 help me with the code/logic for defining web root in a situation like this. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "define":

```
define('ROOT', '/home/username/public_html/');
```

Then, in any page that the page this is defined in is included:

```
echo ROOT;
```

Comment: yeah i did that, but when i try to access some files in the users folder, it's calling the constant from the users folder, instead of from the root.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] - define some constant with what's here and away you go.

Comment: yeah i did that, but when i try to access some files in the users folder, it's calling the constant from the users folder, instead of from the root.